# Dumpcap on remote linux interface

Tags: linux, wireshark

I want to capture packets on a remote linux interface using dumpcap. I have observed that there is a command - `dumpcap -i rpcap://<host>/<interface>` and `dumpcap -i TCP@<host>:<port>`

But when trying to execute the later command the terminal says that the connection is refused.

Following is the output received.

`dumpcap: The capture session could not be initiated due to the socket error:
        111: Connection refused`

If someone can provide me with the background requirements that should be fulfilled in order to do this, I would really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

> If someone can provide me with the background requirements that should be fulfilled in order to do this

You need to be running the appropriate server on the remote machine.  You'll have to look for a version of rpcapd that runs on the Linux distribution on that remote machine, and install it (whether it's a binary package or a source package that needs compilation).  A search for "rpcapd linux" will find some links.

Comment: I was able to find `rpcapd` service in [link](http://www.pawelko.net/rpcapd-for-linux-remote-sniffing-with-etherealwireshark/). But when I run it in the remote machine It gives

`Press CTRL + C to stop the server...`
`bind(): Address already in use (code 98)`

Also when I try to capture packets using commnand `dumpcap -i TCP@<host>:<port>` it doesnt give any error as in before, but doesnt capture any packets as well. Also this works only for `-i TCP@<host>:<port>` format